# How to send spring batch chunk size from UI

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Can someone help to understand how the chunk size 1 or 10 can be supplied from spring controller to step as a variable.
Whether this will work with step scope  here? or have to write in @beforeStep?

@Bean

```
public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<Person, Person> chunk(**10**)
            .reader(reader(null))
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are trying to do it won't work.  In order for a value to be passed in as a job parameter, the object it's being set on needs to be step scoped and a step itself can't be step scoped.  What you could do is create a step scoped `CompletionPolicy` that uses that to determine if the chunk is complete.  In short, configuring the Spring Batch `CountingCompletionPolicy` as a step scoped bean and configuring your step with that should allow you to set the max count via a job parameter.

You can read more about the `CompletionPolicy` and it's related implementations here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/repeat/CompletionPolicy.html

Comment: I am not trying to change the chunk when the batch is running. I just want to set it before job starts. Is that also need to happen with "CompletionPolicy" ?

Comment: Yes.  The issue you're facing is the order of when objects are created.  Your step is created before the job parameters are parsed so we don't have a way to inject it.  By using a `CompletionPolicy` and making it step scoped, you can delay when that value is used until it's needed (and actually available).